# Update ThemeResources from c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, themes, uwp

I've got a void that analyses an image, extracts two dominant colors, and replaces "SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" and "SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush", that I'm overriding in App.xaml. It works well, except that it takes a bit of time to analyse the image, so it changes the colors once all the controls in my page have already loaded.
As a result, they stay the old accent color. How can I get them to bind dynamically to that ThemeRessource?

Here's my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Name="resdic">
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is the (very simplified) part of the ColorExtractor.cs class that changes the colors:

```
public async static void Analyse()
{
    Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(color2);
}
```

And I've got a bunch of controls in Page.xaml that have their Foreground set as such:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush]"/>
```

I call `ColorExtractor.Analyse()` in my Page.xaml.cs (at the OnNavigatedTo event). I can always create an event that gets fired once the colors are set, but I need to find a way to update the colors of all the controls in my page once that's done.

Comment: Can you please post some code to help me understand what you are doing? You can try to bind a property to `ThemeResource` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this property.

Comment: I've updated my OP with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to create an event in ColorExtractor.cs :

```
public static event EventHandler Analysed;
public async static void  Analyse(BitmapImage poster)
{
    //Analyse colors
    Analysed(null, null);
}
```

And then, on my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
ColorExtractor.Analyse(bmp);
ColorExtractor.Analysed += (sender, EventArgs) =>
{
    //Set Page foreground color, as a lot of controls are dynamically binded to their parent's foreground brush.
    //If a control isn't automatically binded, all I have to do is say: Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=page}"
    page.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
    page.BorderBrush = Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
    //Reload any custom user control that sets it's children's color when it's loaded.
    backdrop.UserControl_Loaded(null, null);
};
```

So I'm not actually binding my controls to the ForegroundAccentBrush directly, but this works without needing to re-navigate to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at how Template 10 does theming changes, but in their case they are defining two different themes in resource dictionaries in advance. You can find their code in the [repo on Github](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10), but here are some of the code used:

```
(Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement).RequestedTheme = value.ToElementTheme();
Views.Shell.SetRequestedTheme(value, UseBackgroundChecked);
```

From [here](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Samples/DynamicThemes/Services/SettingsServices/SettingsService.cs)

```
public static void SetRequestedTheme(ApplicationTheme theme, bool UseBackgroundChecked)
    {

        WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            (Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement).RequestedTheme = theme.ToElementTheme();

            ParseStyleforThemes(theme);

            HamburgerMenu.NavButtonCheckedForeground = NavButtonCheckedForegroundBrush;

            HamburgerMenu.NavButtonCheckedBackground = (UseBackgroundChecked) ?
                NavButtonCheckedBackgroundBrush : NavButtonBackgroundBrush;

            HamburgerMenu.NavButtonCheckedIndicatorBrush = (UseBackgroundChecked) ?
                Colors.Transparent.ToSolidColorBrush() : NavButtonCheckedIndicatorBrush;

            HamburgerMenu.SecondarySeparator = SecondarySeparatorBrush;

            List<HamburgerButtonInfo> NavButtons = HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons.ToList();
            NavButtons.InsertRange(NavButtons.Count, HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons.ToList());

            List<HamburgerMenu.InfoElement> LoadedNavButtons = new List<HamburgerMenu.InfoElement>();

            foreach (var hbi in NavButtons)
            {
                StackPanel sp = hbi.Content as StackPanel;
                if (hbi.ButtonType == HamburgerButtonInfo.ButtonTypes.Literal) continue;
                ToggleButton tBtn = sp.Parent as ToggleButton;
                Button btn = sp.Parent as Button;

                if (tBtn != null)
                {
                    var button = new HamburgerMenu.InfoElement(tBtn);
                    LoadedNavButtons.Add(button);
                }
                else if (btn != null)
                {
                    var button = new HamburgerMenu.InfoElement(btn);
                    LoadedNavButtons.Add(button);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Rectangle indicator = tBtn.FirstChild<Rectangle>();
                indicator.Visibility = ((!hbi.IsChecked ?? false)) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;

                if (!hbi.IsChecked ?? false) continue;

                ContentPresenter cp = tBtn.FirstAncestor<ContentPresenter>();
                cp.Background = NavButtonCheckedBackgroundBrush;
                cp.Foreground = NavButtonCheckedForegroundBrush;
            }

            LoadedNavButtons.ForEach(x => x.RefreshVisualState());

        });
    }
```

From [here](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Samples/DynamicThemes/Views/Shell.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a void that analyses an image, extracts two dominant colors, and replaces "SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" and "SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush", that I'm overriding in App.xaml.

First I don't think your code in app.xaml can override the `ThemeResource`, and you used this `Brush` in the Page like this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" Text="Hello World!" FontSize="50" />
```

If you press "F12" on the `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush`, you can find this resource actually in the "generic.xaml" file.

Now suppose your `ColorExtractor.cs` class works fine and `ColorExtractor.Analyse()` can override the color of those two brushes, and you have many controls in the page uses these two resources, refreshing the Page here can solve your problem.

But I think it's better that not put this operation in `OnNavagateTo` event or `Page.Loaded` event, there is no refresh method in UWP, we use navigating again to this page to refresh, so if putting this operation in `OnNavagateTo` event or `Page.Loaded` event, every time you navigate to this page, the resources will be overrided and it will navigate again. So I put this operation in a Button click event like this:

```
public bool Reload()
{
    return Reload(null);
}

private bool Reload(object param)
{
    Type type = this.Frame.CurrentSourcePageType;
    if (this.Frame.BackStack.Any())
    {
        type = this.Frame.BackStack.Last().SourcePageType;
        param = this.Frame.BackStack.Last().Parameter;
    }
    try { return this.Frame.Navigate(type, param); }
    finally
    {
        this.Frame.BackStack.Remove(this.Frame.BackStack.Last());
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColorExtractor.Analyse();
    Reload();
}
```